# Will conversion from Mountain Lion to Mavericks affect my iOS Developer certificate

Tags: certificate, osx-mountain-lion, osx-mavericks

I've been learning to program using Xcode 4.6.3 for a year now and have just recently enrolled into the Apple Developer Program. For practical reasons, I've chosen to stay on Xcode 4 until I'm well versed with all the software, device provisioning and app submission. Eventually, I'll convert to Mavericks, Xcode5 and finally code for iOS7.

My question is : If I create and install a certificate in Mountain Lion, what will happen when I move into Mavericks?

Comment: Nothing will happen. It will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

nothing will happen, all Certificates will stay valid.

but maybe the provisioning profiles needing updates if use iOS7 libs
but xcode will doe that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say that everything was not fine for me. I have recently migrated to Maveric(10.9) from Mountain Lion (10.8.5). Though I opened my previous login.keychain file with KeyChain Access, it did not worked for me. I have lost my developer-certificate's private key.
[image]

I have found another way to take back-up of your developer's account details.
Open Xcode preferences->account. Export your accounts and save them properly.
[image]

After migrating to Maverick or Yosemite import the file to your Xcode.